# Can I mute a foreground app using ADB commands?

Tags: android, audio, adb

I have this adb shell command to mute an app with **known package name**

> cmd appops set com.app.name PLAY_AUDIO deny

Rather than this, I want to send an adb command to **mute the app which is currently in the foreground**. What should be the adb command modification that will be required?

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

I found out the answer myself. The Tasker (android app) has the Appinfo function, whereby we can store the name of the foreground app in a local variable, and then we can run the ADB command using that local variable.